# Change displayed name of a project in the Solution Explore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have several projects in my solution. One of them is an external dependency located outside the solution root folder. Unfortunately, it's named the same as a project in this solution. I'd like to make it shown under a different name in the Solution Explorer only, w/o physically renaming the project files. I've tried to change it by editing the solution file, namely (pun not intended) replacing

```
Project(<snip>) = "SameName", "..\path\Project.csproj", "<snip>"
```

by

```
Project(<snip>) = "UniqueName", "..\path\Project.csproj", "<snip>"
```

but no visible changes occured.

How else can I do this? Why are there seemingly unused project names in the solution?

Comment: *"Unfortunately, it's named the same as a project in this solution"* - do you have difficulties to identify which project is which or is the problem more severe? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: In your solution, what if you created a folder for the other project? Or is there also a compile conflict (similar dll names, etc)?

Comment: For now it's mainly about correctly identifying them at a glance, plus not having newcomers to become confused as to why are there two projects with identical names. As to the other question, unfortunately I don't seem to understand it well. What's that creating a new folder supposed to do? In what sense is it "created"? There are no conflicts as of now.

Comment: @ZzZombo, have you tried to rename your project manually? Please right-click the project node and then select Rename from the context menu. I think it is the direct way to do it.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT: no, it renames the project file as well.

Comment: @ZzZombo, based on my further research, I find that it is hard for us to find a direct way to only change the display name without changing the project file. I also tried some methods such as command line and code to change it. However, it will also change the  project file name.